# OperationalError: (1317, 'Query execution was interrupted') during migration

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm encountering a problem with Django migrations, specifically encountering an `OperationalError (1317, 'Query execution was interrupted')` during the migration process.

This issue arises when executing the `python manage.py migrate` command. It's worth noting that this problem doesn't occur locally; rather, it's specific to the production environment during migration. The process seems to get stuck at the migration for approximately 1 minute before ultimately raising the error outlined below.

```
Applying accounts.0049_userprofile_description...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 75, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 254, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb.OperationalError: (1317, 'Query execution was interrupted')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/****/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 96, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 349, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 135, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 167, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 252, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 130, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 108, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/schema.py", line 105, in add_field
    super().add_field(model, field)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 682, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 199, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/__init__.py", line 563, in execute
    return real_execute(self, sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 75, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 254, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
  django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1317, 'Query execution was interrupted')
```

I have attempted the migration multiple times and increased the database timeout settings, but unfortunately, the issue persists. Your assistance in resolving this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please run this query: `SELECT @@max_execution_time;` and report the result.

Comment: Thank you. But I think it was caused by migrations maxing out the cpu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I identified that the CPU was reaching its maximum capacity during the migration process. To address this, I increased the server resources. Following this adjustment, the migration proceeded smoothly without encountering the previous issues.